# Are haiku typically "padded" when read aloud?

Tags: poetry

I was once told that haiku should be "padded" so that instead of 5/7/5, they fit an 8/8/8 meter:

> ■■■■■□□□　←　wait for 3 beats after this line
>   ■■■■■■■□　←　wait for 1 beat after this line
>   ■■■■■□□□　←　wait for 3 beats after this line

If I recall correctly, the explanation was that Japanese favors rhythms in groups of 4 or 8 beats (morae).  I don't actually know if haiku are read this way, though--it's just something I was told once.

Are haiku actually read aloud with these pauses?  Or is this something my friend made up?

Comment: Holy crap, I do this automatically and I never noticed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I think you'd read it as:

> ■■■■■□□□ 
>   ■■■■■■■□　
>   ■■■■■□□□

for 5/7/5 like [かたつむり・・・](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1YJ9B4eoecl) where the middle line can be split into 4+3(e.g.: トウキョウ・ナゴヤ).

And you'd read it as:

> ■■■■■□□□ 　
>   □■■■■■■■　 
>   ■■■■■□□□

for 5/7/5 like [静かさや・・・](http://vocaroo.com/i/s07exKb7uVUZ) where the middle line sounds better when split into 3+4(e.g.: カワズ・トビコム).

And you'd probably read it as:

> ■■■■■□□□ 　
>   ■■■■■■■■　
>   ■■■■■□□□

for 5/8/5, like [8/5/8/5/8/5... :D](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1cskQXEvEOg)([唱歌・カタツムリ](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%83%84%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AA#.E3.81.8B.E3.81.9F.E3.81.A4.E3.82.80.E3.82.8A.EF.BC.88.E5.94.B1.E6.AD.8C.EF.BC.89)、[童謡・鳩](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%B3%A9_%28%E7%AB%A5%E8%AC%A1%29#.E5.8E.9F.E5.85.B8.E3.81.AB.E3.82.88.E3.82.8B.E6.AD.8C.E8.A9.9E)より)

Comment: wwwwちょこれーと東京名古屋かたつむり。最高のアンサーだわ、これｗ

Comment: いい俳句が思いつかなかったんで・・・^^;

Comment: Yup! And according to [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Japanese-Linguistics-Advanced-Learners/dp/1483935493/ref=cm_cr_pr_pb_t) (p171, 2.14 Rhythm in "Haiku"), that also explains why 「ニッポン」, rather than 「にほん」, is used for cheering.

Comment: Interesting. Are there any recorded examples of this out there?

Comment: @RoyFuentes I recorded my reading on Vocaroo and pasted the links up here. For more... how about this [百人一首 読み上げ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l02UzbJlkIw&index=10&list=PLuoIEgeIX7y7OEcBNuhNNkCic8snzKrei), not the same words/songs, though.